# Position absolute not working

Tags: html, css

So this is my code

```
<a href="#" style="float:left; position:absolute; left:0px; "><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/3lnt8f1s3    /32_facebook.png"></a>
```

and the position is apparently absolute. But it doesn't "stick" to the side of the page. Any ideas? Here's a demo http://jsbin.com/kelagezo/1/edit

Comment: It sticks perfectly to the side of the page. What do you expect?

Comment: It's worked, as should

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are confusing `position: absolute` with `position: fixed`.

Fixed positioning leaves the element where it is when you scroll.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
position:fixed
```

instead of

```
position: absolute.
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v3GyF/2/

While you are at it, please try not to mix HTML and CSS. Its always a better policy to keep them seperate. This is called **Seperation of concerns**

Answer (score -2):

It does stick to the left browser window edge. You don't need `float:left` when `absolute` or `fixed` positioning.